# Is Xml serialization available in .NET Maui?

Tags: c#, .net, maui, .net-maui, maui-blazor

I'm starting developing a simple application in .NET Maui, trying to load some data structures from a XML file.

Unfortunately when I call the XmlSerializer constructor

```
var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
```

it gives me the following exception:

> 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib.XmlSerializers, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, processorArchitecture=AMD64'

The xml file path is correct and it exists, and I've tested the code in a different project (not Maui).

Comment: while debugging? That is a standard normally hidden exception that you might see because of your exception handling settings in VS and you can simply ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a `known issue` about this problem.

You can follow it here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8322.

Thanks for your feedback and patience.