# MAUI XMLSerializer

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, maui

I've looked at this question: [Is Xml serialization available in .NET Maui?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73687118/is-xml-serialization-available-in-net-maui)

I'm not sure if the linked github issue is the same.

I can't be the only person who has tried to consume a ASMX SOAP service in MAUI? I have built an app and it runs absolutely perfectly (well almost) in Debug mode. But as soon as I build the app in release mode I get

```
"There was an error in serializing body of message <x>: 'There was an error generating the XML document.'.  
Please see inner exception for more details.   
At System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeBody(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object returnValue, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
```

The inner Exception:

```
There was an error generating the XML document   
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
```

With a further inner exception of:

```
Invalid IL code in Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterLDBServiceSoap:Write63_Item.
```

How can it build ok in debug but not in release? Ive checked various things, and im running out of ideas. Any hints at all?

Obviously I dont think i can 'Step Through' the code in release mode because its release mode :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps:

1.try to remove the bin and obj folders ,then uninstall the previous versions of the app from your device, and try again;

2.if the problem persist, try to set the `Linker behavior` to Don't link and try again;

3.try to disable `AOT` compilation;

Comment: Thanks for the reply, ive been trying various things along the line you suggest, but unfortunately still the same result. The linker behaviour would this be on the Xml Serializer NuGet package ?

Comment: For the Linking behavior in maui, you can check document: [Linking a .NET MAUI Android app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/linking?tabs=vs).

Comment: Unfortunately this still isnt working. Ive managed to get debug symbols included on the release build, and ive updated the original question. Appreciate any feedback you can give..

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered very similar behavior. This issue appears only in Android in release build.

Android platform supports dynamically generated code and XML serialization assembly generates in runtime. Playing with AOT and linkage settings had no success.

Then I had try to generate XML serialization library within build process via Microsoft.XmlSerializer.Generator (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/xml-serializer-generator).

When building with this package and few settings like additional properties in csproj-file (`<SGenTypes>YouClassForSerialization</SGenTypes><SGenVerbose>true</SGenVerbose>`) I saw in build log some warnings about the serialization process.

I had fix the warning issues and release build start works just fine (without Microsoft.XmlSerializer.Generator package).

In my case I use ShouldSerializeXXX pattern in serialized class and method ShouldSerialiseXXX was static but not the instance. Removing of the static modifier had fix the issue.